# App Engine Datastore ignoring "noindex" tag in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using go version go1.6.2 (appengine-1.9.40) darwin/amd64

When saving a struct to the datastore, slices of structs which have been tagged as "noindex", are showing up as indexed in the datastore viewer, while non struct fields are correctly showing as unindexed

As an example, I have:

```
Type User struct{
  Email string
  Buddies []Buddy `datastore:",noindex"`
  Language string `datastore:",noindex"`
}

Type Buddy struct{
  Name string `datastore:",noindex"`
  Age int `datastore:",noindex"`
}
```

When saving a new `User` to the datastore, the datastore viewer shows the properties `Buddies.Name` and `Buddies.Age` as "Indexed" despite the fact that I've tagged them as "noindex".

How do I get the datastore to not index structs?

Comment: Where do you see that `Buddies.Name` is indexed? I've tried what you posted, and it works for me (`User` gets indexed by `Email` for example, but not by `Buddies.Age`).

Comment: Just in case it's relevant: be aware that entities already in the datastore will remain indexed even if you change a field to `noindex`, until you save it again.

Comment: @icza I see it in the datastore viewer.

Comment: @EricSimonton I completely wiped the entire datastore to be sure that there wasn't anything there already, and it still shows up as indexed in the datastore viewer.

Comment: But where? Because I don't even see stated that the `Email` property is indexed, even though it is.

Comment: @icza the code shown is an almost exact copy of what I have, but I can't share the exact code I have due to a NDA.  In the cloud console, select "datastore", then select "User" as the Kind, and open one of the User entities. There is a column listing "Indexed" next to every indexed value.

Comment: I was checking it locally, will check in production. Btw testing it locally, filtering or sorting by `Buddies.Age` gives no result which means that property is not indexed. You can test that in your prod environment.

Comment: @icza I can only filter by "Email", which is the one field that I want indexed, so it may just be that the datastore viewer is giving incorrect information.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Has anyone was able to get to the bottom of it?